# How to rotate a view on iOS

Tags: ios, face-detection, core-image

I use CoreImage on iOS for face detection. I already did this using [this helpful tutorial](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5)
. My problem is I added it in a View Controller, I'm able to rotate the image to match the circle drawn over the eyes and mouth but I can't rotate the whole view controller. Is there a better approach.

My image is look like this.

[image]

I want to rotate it upside down.

I'm using storyboard and ios7

Answer (score 0):

Actually the coordinate system of the CoreImage & iOS is different. CoreImage is using exactly opposite coordinate systems as iPhone so you must convert the mouth & eye points according to the iOS coordinate system.

Refer the 5th point here:-

5) Adjust For The Coordinate System

http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5

Comment: I use it inside my viewcontroller not in appdelegate. It's not working when I do it in my view controller.

Comment: It's not depend on where you are taking in your viewcontroller or in appDelegate. You are facing issues only because the coordinate system differences.